# Creating layout using Angular directives

Tags: angularjs

Folks.. i am trying to layout a bunch of columns in tablular format using Angular directive but am lost after having written some code.

What's the issue?
I need to display a bunch of columns as shown in the plnkr (Display option 2). However I want to achieve this using directives.

Here is the plnkr: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/yTDxfvkCJHwrEDZGQJeX

Any help will be appreciated

regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a template to the directive, you can output the same markup as your first example:

```
demo.directive("customTable",function(){
    return ({
            restrict : "A",            
            template: '<span ng-repeat="element in header" ng-style="{width: element.width}" class="box">{{element.column}}</span>'
    });
    function link($scope, element, attributes){      
      console.log($scope.header);
      console.log("now what");
    }
 });
```

This one uses the parent scope so you don't need the header attribute:

```
  <h1>Display option 2: Use Directive </h1>
  <div custom-table>
  </div>
```

Here is an [updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IMcIuT?p=preview).

You could also use Isolated Scope and two-way bind the header.  This allows the header object to be bound between the parent scope and the directive scope:

```
 demo.directive("customTable",function(){
    return ({
            restrict : "A",  
            scope: {
                header = '='
            },          
            template: '<span ng-repeat="element in header" ng-style="{width: element.width}" class="box">{{element.column}}</span>'
    });
    function link($scope, element, attributes){      
      console.log($scope.header);
      console.log("now what");
    }
 });
```

And then you can declare `header` as you did originally:

```
  <h1>Display option 2: Use Directive </h1>
  <div custom-table header="header">
  </div>
```

Comment: Davin.. this works fine in smaller scheme of things.. but my ultimate goal is to be able to align values below each column. Please see thread here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21615477/aligning-elements-using-angularjs-directives