# Aligning elements using Angularjs directives

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a table-like effect using Angular directives.

I am able to align the header columns now and am trying to understand how the other elements can be aligned below the header.

Plnkr here: http://plnkr.co/edit/yTDxfvkCJHwrEDZGQJeX

Kindly advice

Answer (score 0):

If you can slightly adjust your body values so that they occur in the correct order:

```
   $scope.body = [
                 ['abc','def','ghi','jkl'],
                 ['123','456','789','222'] 
              ];
```

Then, you can do this in a template easily.  Here is an example with Isolated Scope:

```
demo.directive("customTable",function(){
    return ({
            restrict : "A",
            scope: {
              header: '=',
              body: '='
            },
             template: '<table class="box"><tr><th ng-repeat="head in header">{{head.column}}</th></tr><tr ng-repeat="row in body"><td ng-repeat="cell in row">{{ cell }}</td></tr></table>'
    });
    function link($scope, element, attributes){      
      /* how to make the elements in $scope.body coincide with those in $scope.header*/
    }
 });
```

And here is a [forked plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/05rQVi?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks for replying Davin.. the elements won't always be in the correct order and we want to avoid using table tags.. any clues ?

Comment: Do you want to re-invent a grid, or can you use ng-grid?  ng-grid does not use table tags and can do everything you want and much more.

Comment: not trying to reinvent the grid .. but require this functionality as I don't want to include the entire ng-grid eco system.